# How can I format String alignment-left

Tags: ios, string, swift

Firstly I found it is easy for me to format other type, Such as Int, for Example:

```
let i = 12345
let s = String(format: "%-10d", 12345)
//then s = "12345     "
```

The right-hand-side a few space is exactly what I need!

But when I try to implement it to a String (Am I right if I use "%@"?)

```
let str = "12345"
let s = String(format: "%-10@", str)
//then s = "12345" rather than "12345     "
```

How could I do it to achieve the same result?

Comment: `%@` doesn't support such modifiers for some reason. I filed a bug report with Apple about this (which was closed as a duplicate). In Objective-C I would use `%-10s` and pass in the C-string version of the string. Not sure how to do that in Swift.

Comment: @rmaddy. Thank you buddy! I also tried the "%-10s" it return me a "" string. So there must be some bugs :D thank you for you comment :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use String method stringByPaddingToLength()

```
let str = "12345"
let paddedString = str.stringByPaddingToLength(10, withString: " ", startingAtIndex: 0)   // "12345     "
```

If you would like to add leading characters to your string You can try creating a custom extension as follow:

```
extension String {
    func stringByAppendingLeadingCharacterToLength(newLenght: Int, withCharacter: Character) -> String {
        return newLenght-characters.count > 0 ? String(count: newLenght-characters.count, repeatedValue: withCharacter) + self : self
    }
}

let strNumbers = "12345"
let paddedString1 = strNumbers.stringByAppendingLeadingCharacterToLength(10, withCharacter: "0")  // "0000012345"
```

---

Xcode 8.2 • Swift 3.0.2

```
extension String {
    func paddingLeft(with character: Character, maxLength: Int) -> String {
        return maxLength - characters.count > 0 ? String(repeating: String(character), count: maxLength - characters.count) + self : self
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
"12345".paddingLeft(with: "0", maxLength: 10)   // "0000012345"
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works well ! And after this I was considering that is there any way to alignment right side?

Comment: @Microos not that I know but you can create a custom extension if you would like to. See my edit