# Passing Swift strings as C strings in variable argument lists

Tags: c, swift

I am trying to use the old printf-style string formatters to define a new Swift string from an old Swift string.

I notice this works fine as long as I am starting with a Swift string literal, but not a string variable.

```
// OK!
String(format:"%s", "hello world".cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))

// ERROR:  argument type '[CChar]?' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArgType'
let s = "hello world"
String(format:"%s", s.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

Why does this happen?

And what's the best workaround?

(Please note that I am aware of but do not want to use the Cocoa string formatter `%@`. I want the printf-style formatting code because what I'm actually trying to do is get quick and dirty tabular alignment with codes like `%-10s`.)

This question concerns Swift 2.2.

Comment: Interesting. What happens if you annotate the type on `s` to be `String`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a C string just for alignment. There is a method [stringByPaddingToLength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405460/how-can-i-format-string-alignment-left) for that.

```
// Swift 2
s.stringByPaddingToLength(10, withString: " ", startingAtIndex: 0)

// Swift 3
s.padding(toLength: 10, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)
```

Note that it will truncate the string if it is longer than 10 UTF-16 code units.

---

The problem here is, there are two methods in Swift named `cStringUsingEncoding`:

1. `func cStringUsingEncoding(encoding: UInt) -> UnsafePointer<Int8>`, as a method of NSString
2. `func cStringUsingEncoding(encoding: NSStringEncoding) -> [CChar]?`, as an extension of String

If we want a pointer, we need to ensure we are using an NSString, not a String.

In the first example, a string literal can be a String or NSString, so the compiler chooses NSString since the other one won't work.

But in the second example, the type of `s` is already set to String, so the method that returns `[CChar]?` is chosen.

This could be worked-around by forcing `s` to be an NSString:

```
let s: NSString = "hello world"
String(format:"%s", s.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

Answer (score 0):

kennytm's answer is clearly the best way.

But for anyone else who is still wondering about how to do it the wrong way, and get access to a c string based on a Swift String without going through NSString, this also seems to work (Swift 2.2):

```
var s:String  = "dynamic string"
s.nulTerminatedUTF8.withUnsafeBufferPointer { (buffptr) -> String in
  let retval:String = String(format:"%s",buffptr.baseAddress)
  return retval
}
```

Comment: Simpler: Use `s.withCString { ... }`.